# Does there exist a power of 2 whose last 100 digits are composed only of the digits 1 or 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does there exist a power of 2 whose last 100 digits are composed only of the digits 1 or 2? If so, what techniques could be used to prove its existence?

Comment: Well a power of 2 is divisible by 2, so its final digit cannot be a 1.

Comment: The last digit will always be even since any power of two is an even number. Thus the first cannot happen for this simple reason already.

Comment: Note that for a power of $2$, the last $k$ digits of the power of $2$ must be such that $2^k$ is a divisor.

So, this implies that if there were such a number, the last two digits are $12$ in that order, and likewise, it's not hard to show that if two such powers of $2$ exist, their last $100$ digits are the same.

Comment: Obviously, there is no such number if you want all $1$s or all $2$s, since $4\nmid11,22$

Comment: @RossGreer I believe you're asking for the last $100$ digits being composed of only the digits $1$ and $2$, instead of being just all $1$ *or* just all $2$ (with the latter case not being possible as [Don Thousand](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/572204/don-thousand)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508004/does-there-exist-a-power-of-2-whose-last-100-digits-are-all-1s-or-2s#comment7215028_3508004) shows). Since this is not completely clear as your question is currently worded, please edit it to make it clear what you're specifically asking for.

Comment: $2^1=2, 2^9=512, 2^{89}=61289...9562112,2^{589}=20261...43322112,...$

Comment: @JohnOmielan, Thank you- I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @DonThousand, your first statement is not immediately apparent to me. Is there a book, article, or exercise you would recommend to convince myself of the fact?

Comment: @RossGreer:  it's a generalization of the rule for [divisibility by 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_4), and cf. reference 3 in that Wikipedia article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $q_n$ for $n>0$ be the recurring sequence of natural numbers defined by:
>   \begin{align}
> &q_1=1&&q_{k+1}=\frac{q_k+5^k(2-q_k\bmod 2)}2
> \end{align}
>   then for every $k>0$ the number $a_k=2^kq_k$ satisfy:
>
> 1. $0<a_k<10^k$;
> 2. the decimal digits of $a_k$ belongs to $\{1,2\}$;
> 3. there exists $m\geq k$ such that $2^m\equiv a_k\pmod{10^k}$.

While (1) and (2) are easily proved by induction, to prove (3), note that $5\nmid q_k$, for otherwise $10\mid a_k$ but this would implies that the last digit of $a_k$ is zero - a contradiction.
Since $2$ is a primitive root modulo $5^k$, there exists $n>0$ such that
$$2^n\equiv q_k\pmod{5^k}$$
Then multiplying by $2^k$, we get
$$2^{n+k}\equiv a_k\pmod{10^k}$$

---

To generate the recurrence above: assume $2^m\equiv a_k\pmod{10^k}$ with $m\geq k$ and $a_k=2^kq_k$ and let $2^n\equiv 10^kd+a_k\pmod{10^{k+1}}$ with $d\in\{1,2\}$ and $n\geq k+1$.
Dividing by $2^k$ we get $2^{n-k}\equiv 5^kd+q_k\pmod{2\cdot 5^{k+1}}$, hence reducing modulo $2$, we get $d\equiv -q_k\pmod 2$.
Since $d\in\{1,2\}$, we have $d=2-q_k\bmod 2$.
Moreover,
$$2^n\equiv 2^k(5^kd+q_k)=2^{k+1}q_{k+1}\pmod{10^{k+1}}$$
where $q_{k+1}=\frac{q_k+5^kd}2$.

Comment: How did you generate your recurrence relation? Is this a specific case of a generalized approach?

Comment: @RossGreer: I generate it by solving recursively the congruence $2^m\equiv a_k\pmod{10^k}$.

Comment: In solving the congruence, I could make the claim that $a_k = 2^m (1+x*10^k)$ for some x. Then, $a_k = 2^k 2^{m-k}(1+x*10^k)$. But, your recurrence introduces mod and eliminates m. Is there a way to reach this point from here?

Comment: @ROS: I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much; very clear now!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't think I needed to write an answer, but since there have been quite a few incorrect approaches noted so far, I'm going to write up a more detailed version of the comments I posted yesterday.

First off, let me prove the claim that given a power of $2$, let's say $2^k$, $k\in\mathbb N$, for any $n\leq k$, the last $n$ digits of $2^k$ has $2^n$ as a divisor.

Note that $2^n\mid 2^k$, and if we denote $m_n$ to be the last $n$ digits of $2^k$, then $$2^k\equiv m_n\bmod{10^n}$$Since $2\mid 10$, this implies $$2^k\equiv m_n\bmod{2^n}$$But, we already said that $2^n\mid 2^k\to2^k\equiv0\bmod{2^n}$. Hence, $$m_n\equiv0\bmod{2^n}$$

Knowing this, it's easy to show that it's not possible to have a power of two ending in $100$ $1$s or $2$, since $4\not\mid11,22$.

So, we know that the last $n$ digits of our chosen number must be divisible by $2^n$. We can use this fact for $n=1\to100$ to find what the last $100$ digits of the power of $2$ (if it exists) must be.

Before we do this, it's worth observing why these last $100$ digits are unique. Note that at position $1\leq n\leq 100$ (where position $1$ is the units digits, $2$ the tens, etc), we have the choice of either $1$ or $2$. Using the notation from before, we know that $2^{n-1}\mid m_{n-1}$, so $m_{n-1}\equiv2^{n-1}\bmod{2^n}$, or $m_{n-1}\equiv0\bmod{2^n}$. Note that $1\cdot10^{n-1}\equiv2^{n-1}\bmod{2^n}$ and $2\cdot10^{n-1}\equiv0\bmod{2^n}$, so when $m_{n-1}\equiv2^{n-1}\bmod{2^n}$, placing $1$ in position $n$ satisfies the condition presented above, while placing $2$ doesn't, and vice versa when $m_{n-1}\equiv0\bmod{2^n}$.

This establishes the uniqueness of the last $100$ digits. I generated these digits using python:

> $12112112112211212112111211221222112122211121221111222121122121211121211211$ $22111112111211111212122112$

Comment: The line break is intentional, as on certain browsers, the format messes up wildly sin line break

Comment: I noticed your remark "(if it exists)"; I understand how your procedure can generate these 100 unique last digits, but are we guaranteed that these are the last 100 digits of a power of 2? We have established that if this power exists, it is unique, but I am attempting to find proof of the existence.

Comment: @Ross The other answer guarantees existence.